# Rate expression with water as one of the reactants

Tags: kinetics

When finding an equation for d[A]/dt from reaction mechanisms and $\ce{H2O}$ is a product/reactant, does $\ce{H2O}$ have to be included or left out like for equilibrium constant expressions?

For example, in the reaction of carbon dioxide with water,

$$\ce{CO2(aq) + H2O(l) -> H2CO3(aq)}$$

which expression describes the kinetics correctly (assuming that the reaction above shows the elementary step):

$$ \mathrm{rate} = k_1 \cdot [\ce{CO2(aq)}] \tag{1}$$
or

$$ \mathrm{rate} = k_2 \cdot [\ce{CO2(aq)}] \cdot [\ce{H2O(l)}] \tag{2}$$

Comment: I think people will ask you to reformulate the question, as it's not clear and lacks relevant details. E.g. is water a solvent as well? Because then what usually happens is that you consider its concentration approximately constant (as it is most of the time much larger than the one of the other reagents), and that makes it 'disappear' from the rate law. So e.g. a reaction with order 2 where one of the reactants is water becomes 'pseudo first order', just because the concentration of water becomes part of the constant.

Comment: Ask yourself, if there are cases when you can consider [H2O] being constant, including it implicitly into the rate constant.

Comment: In the dissolution of $\ce{CO2}$ in water, the concentration of $\ce{H2O}$ may be considered as constant.